# can't create the table (ERROR 1005 (HY000):errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, table, mariadb

В чем моя ошибка, не могу создать таблицу `movies_genres`.

```
CREATE TABLE movies( 
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  title VARCHAR (400) NOT NULL, 
  duration INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE genres(
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
genre VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
)ENGINE  = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE movies_genres(
movie_id INT NOT NULL,
genre_id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(movie_id, genre_id),
FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(genre_id) REFERENCES genres(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
ENGINE  = InnoDB;
```

> **ERROR 1005 (HY000):** Can't create table .`movies_genres` (errno: 150 "For eign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: типы `movie_id` и `genre_id` не соответствуют типам `id` полей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании внешнего ключа типы данных должны совпадать. То есть, если в `movies` вы используете `INT UNSIGNED` для `id`, то и в таблице `movies_genres` для поля `movie_id` нужно использовать `INT UNSIGNED` или же перейти к использования `int` для обеих полей.